# XPATH/Xquery navigating a sequence of strings

Tags: xpath, xquery

I have a collection of xml documents, each with an xml:id. For example:

```
<doc xml:id="TC0001">some content<doc>
<doc xml:id="TC0002">some content<doc>
<doc xml:id="TC0003">some content<doc>
<doc xml:id="TC0004">some content<doc>
<doc xml:id="TC0005">some content<doc>
```

I have a function which gets a subset of (maximum) 3 `xml:id`s in a sequence, potential returning the `xml:id` before and after of a given `xml:id`. So, in simple terms, calling this function (XPATH within XQuery):

```
let $myid = "TC0002"
return doc-id-list($myid)
```

returns the sequence: `TC0001, TC0002, TC0003`

And this:

```
let $myid = "TC0001"
return doc-id-list($myid)
```

correctly returns the sequence of two `xml:id`s: `TC0001, TC0002`

All of this works fine. Now I need to process the results, with each xml:id treated differently based on whether it is 'before' $myid, $myid itself, or 'after' $myid.

I'm stuck trying to build a solution that navigates the sequence with the following logic:

- if there is an id 'before' $myid in the sequence, do X with that id
- if there is an id 'after' $myid in the sequence, do Y with that id

Because this eventually outputs HTML, I am looking for something which allows me a solution that doesn't require many nested `if-then-else` statements.

I should note that the `xml:id`s can have gaps, so I can't simply increment the value.

Many thanks for any ideas.

Comment: What's `doc-id-list`?

Comment: Just a thought, Can you simply check position of the `$myid` and then decide if the id position based on index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be nice to know what your real requirement is, and whether forming the sequence in doc-id-list() actually contributes to it.

My instinct would be to do something like

```
let $target := doc[@xml-id=$myId]
return (process-prior($target/preceding-sibling::doc[1]),
        process-target($target),
        process-next($target/following-sibling::doc[1]))
```

Comment: That's a fair criticism...and now I see your instincts are correct: I should treat these as nodes, not string sequence, and then navigate/process them with Xpath axes. Thanks as ever.